object collection give the last row value to all row in laravel
i'm trying to get user answer for every question that they are answer.
but, the answer for every  user is same with the latest user answer.
here is for the controller :
$category_kelas = CategoryKelas::where('id', $category_kelas_id)->with('category', 'kelas')->first();
        $question = Question::where('category_id', $category_kelas->category_id)->get();
        $category_kelas['users'] = UserQuiz::where('category_id', $category_kelas->category_id)->where('kelas_id', $category_kelas->kelas_id)->with('user')->get();
        foreach ($category_kelas->users as  $item) {
            $item['question'] = $question;
        }

        foreach ($category_kelas->users as $item) {
            foreach ($item->question as $item2) {
                $item2['answer'] = UserAnswer::where('user_quiz_id', $item->id)->where('question_id', $item2->id)->first();
            }
        }

and here is for the blade view :
    <tr>
        <th>Jenis Tes</th>
        <th>Kelas</th>
        <th>Peserta</th>
        <th>Selesai</th>
        @foreach ($category_kelas->users as $index => $item)
            @foreach ($item->question as $item2)
                @if ($index == 0)
                    <th>{{ $item2->order_number }}</th>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach ($category_kelas->users as $item)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $category_kelas->category->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $category_kelas->kelas->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->user->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->finish }}</td>
            @foreach ($item->question as $item2)
                <td>{{ $item2->answer->value }}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>

and the result is like this :

the result is using the latest user answerm not its own answer.
please help
